# How to connect multiple faces quickly?

Tags: mesh, faces, vertex-groups

I was given a model that has most of its faces separate from each other. The model will be 3D printed, so I need to make it into a solid object with wall thickness. Is there a way to connect the edges of the faces quickly?

[image: Model without Subdivision Surface]

[image: Model with Subdivision Surface]

Comment: Am not so sure, but under the edit mode, goto>Mesh>Faces and check if there is such option in the options

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60375/why-am-i-getting-rounded-faces-when-combining-edge-split-and-subsurf

Comment: Select every verts then hit "W" then "R" (remove doubles).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but the solution posted in [this comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140676/how-to-connect-multiple-faces-quickly#comment240599_140676) doesn't exist anymore in the newer Blender versions (or at least I couldn't find it), and the [linked answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60375/why-am-i-getting-rounded-faces-when-combining-edge-split-and-subsurf) doesn't address this specific issue.

So to solve the problem and join all the faces together, select all the faces you want merged. Then merge the vertices by distance. To do this you can either

1. hit <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd>, or
2. (in vertex-select mode) right-click, select "Merge Vertices" and select "By Distance."

This should join all the corresponding vertices of your faces, so that they're all connected.