# How can I fix these gaps on the faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I just started to make a little more complicated project on Blender and sometimes these gaps appear on the faces of the object. It happens everytime I apply the edge split and subdivision surface that i use to smooth the base cylinder that I started with.

[image]
[image]

I tried to crease the faces and it resolves the problem of the faces but the curves lose its smoothness and becomes low-poly(thing that i want to avoid).
[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60375/why-am-i-getting-rounded-faces-when-combining-edge-split-and-subsurf

Answer (score 2):

You could smooth your object and go and enable auto smooth if you want a smooth edge. Creating a face shouldn't make this happen, so try merging by distance by pressing `M` > `Merge By Distance`. And don't create another face, you probably accidentally his your faces in edit mode, just press `Alt` + `H` to unhide your faces.